# Using squeeze theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{3n^3+(-1)^nn+4}$$
$$\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{4n^3+4}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]4\sqrt[n]{n^3+1}=1$$
I tried to use the squeeze theorem to find the limit of the first expression, however, I couldn't think of anything for the lower bound.
Can someone give me an idea on how to progress.
thank you

Comment: i can not read your limit

Comment: sorry, it says n to infinity

Comment: Why do you think $\sqrt[n] {3n^3 + (-1)^n*x* n+4} \le \sqrt[n] {3n^3 + (-1)^n n+4}$ ? That's obviously not true for even $n$.

Comment: @fleablood The "×" looked so much like $x$. My edit is my best guess as to what the actual limit was.

Comment: yes @ParclyTaxel is right sorry for the confusion

Comment: What about $1$ for the lower bound ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yh that is the problem i wasn't too sure how to produce the lower bound

Comment: How can you conclude the last equality ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust hmm, the more i look at the problem for more inconclusive the upper inequality seems. I may have to reattempt the upper bound

Comment: the searched limit is $1$

Comment: The question makes no sense:  the limit is over $x$, which is not a variable in the function.  And which root of $(-1)^n$ should one take for arbitrary real value of $n$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork it was a typo the "x" should be an "n"

Comment: zee:  Then please fix your question!

Comment: Isn't it relatively obvious that the radicand is greater than 1 for large n? As such, the nth root must then be greater than or equal to one in the limit. This should complete the proof.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the lower bound is the easier one. We have
$$3n^3+(-1)^nn+4>3n^3-n=n(3n^2-1)$$
which is the product of two increasing sequences, so we get a lower bound of $1\cdot(3-1)=2$. I would go slightly further than your upper bound to be safe, though:
$$3n^3+(-1)^n+4\le4n^3+4\le4n^3+4n^3=8n^3.$$
Taking $n^\text{th}$ roots we have
$$\sqrt[n]{2}\le\sqrt[n]{3n^3+(-1)^nn+4}\le\sqrt[n]{8}(\sqrt[n]{n})^3$$
and so the result follows by the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take $\sqrt[n]{3n^{3}+(-1)^{n}n+4}=1+c_{n}$. Then try to show that $c_{n}$ goes to $0$.

As the hint was not helpful i will try to provide a more elaborate asnwer.
As per the hint we have $3n^{3}+(-1)^{n}n+4=(1+c_{n})^{n}\geq 1+\frac{1}{4!}n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)c_{n}^{4}$ $\Rightarrow$ $c_{n}^{4}\leq \frac{4!(3n^{3}+(-1)^{n}n+3)}{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}$. Hence $\lim_{n}c_{n}\leq 0$. But $c_{n}\geq 0$. Hence $\lim_{n}c_{n}=0$.

Comment: This is basically a rewording of what it means to converge to $1$. I do not see this answer as very helpful.